# json-schema for enumerated properties/keys

Tags: jsonschema

I have a JSON document like this

```
{
   "visits": {
      "1": 1000,
      "2": 300,
      "3": 43,
   }
}
```

But all of the keys (`"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`) are actually an enumeration and it is stored as integer for storage saving purpose. I want to document the description of the enumeration. For example.

```
1 => When the user is guest
2 => When the user is logged in
3 => When the user is admin
```

How do I put this in the json schema?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `patternProperties` to describe the numeric properties, and then `additionalProperties` to disallow any properties that don't match the pattern:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$": {"type": "string"}
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

So here, any property that matches `^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$` (non-negative integer) must be a string, and other properties are not allowed.

*(If you're looking to enforce some kind of ordering (e.g. `"5"` must only exist if `"4"` is also defined) then you can't express that with JSON Schema.)*